# Omiting all heirachy data that matches on a JOIN with a one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, activerecord

Basically, I've got a Heirarchal Tree Table

(buttons)

```
id INT(11),
name VARCHAR(80),
parent_id INT(11),
lft INT(11),
rght INT(11)
```

and a One-to-Many relationship to another table

(kiosk_buttons)

```
id INT(11),
kiosk_id INT(11) "foreign key to kiosk table",
button_id INT(11) "foreign key to buttons table"
```

I've been trying to omit the rows that have a matching buttons.id and kiosk_buttons.button_id while also omitting the children of the matching row.

Here is the query I currently have, it can omit rows but it can't omit it's children.

```
SELECT * 
FROM buttons as b
LEFT JOIN kiosk_buttons as kb
ON b.id = kb.button_id
WHERE kb.button_id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is simply the wrong concept for traversing and looping, it is made for Sets. So if you have a programming language to work with the data, you have to put the traversing there, in a form like your Query, followed by

```
SELECT * 
FROM buttons as b
WHERE b.parent_id in (<last_button_list>)
```

while any results show. Work with that data and set the new list of button_ids as .

But if it comforts you: this way it is easier to work with the data, since a linear list with the whole tree is quite useless.